# Defining width values for xml in String

Tags: android, xml, string

I have dozens of ImageViews in my xml file and defined the length in strings.xml such as `string name="cardWidth">100dp</string>` and then had `content_main.xml` use that string in the width. Like `android:layout_width="@string/cardWidth"` that way I could just change the value once and see how all the images displayed.

No problems with the compile but got a run time error

> Binary XML file line #XX:
>    You must supply a layout_width attribute.

I researched and I saw in S.O. that this will occur when you use a string in the value.  I'll probably just hard code the value once I'm happy with it but is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Sorry for the formatting, it's my first question here!

Answer (score 1):

Your dimension values need to be defined as (possibly in a file `res/values/dimens.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="cardWidth">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then, you can access them using:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/cardWidth"
```

Answer (score 0):

use these width with dimensions in values folder not with string.xml like below :

```
<dimen name="cardWidth">16dp</dimen>
```